# jquery-datatables-rails sort arrows not showing up when deployed to Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, datatables

Running the cedar stack.  When I deploy, the dataTables works but none of the sort arrows show up.
The files not showing up are:
    sort_asc.png
    sort_both.png
    sort_desc.png

They appear when running locally on my development environment. I found this [Images desapears after deploy Rails 3.1.3 on Heroku Cedar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9439562/images-desapears-after-deploy-rails-3-1-3-on-heroku-cedar) and it looks like a similar issue, but I am somewhat new to rails and don't know how to apply that since I'm using a gem.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you precompiled your assets?

There could be a few reasons this doesn't work.  Best bet is start here:

http://www.neilmiddleton.com/heroku-asset-pipeline-faq/

Comment: Just tried a heroku run rake assets:precompile and that didn't do it.  So, I'm reading through the links in your article.

Comment: Thanks. Precompiling assets locally before pushing to heroku did it. RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile

Comment: That was kinda messy having all my assets in the git repo and having to manually precompile before pushing to heroku (which I know you advised against in your article too).  The solution was to put this line in my application.rb: config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false

Comment: Hence the comment "# Heroku REQUIRES this to be false"